# Can't get bar chart to plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Using this code,

```
x = [420.0, 4353.0, 4373.0]; y = [269.0, 252.0, 283.0]
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I get:

[image: Empty bar graph]

Where are the bars? How do I get them to show up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, each bar is plotted with a  width of `0.8` and due to the large range of x values on your plot, that is too narrow to be visible when rendered. You'll instead want to specify a larger width using the `width` kwarg

```
plt.bar(x, y, width=20)
```

[image]
You an also use an array for the `width` value to specify a different width for each bar

```
plt.bar(x, y, width=[3000, 20, 20])
```